# Javascript marge and slice json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Based on this array [json](https://london.my-netdata.io/api/v1/allmetrics?format=json) I need to merge it constantly.
Using push() I get this kind of result

```
JSON
**0:**{
    "net_drops.vpn0": {
        "name":"net_drops.vpn0",
        "context":"net.drops",
        "units":"drops/s",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "inbound": {
                "name": "inbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            },
            "outbound": {
                "name": "outbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }
    },
    "named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default": {
        "name":"named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default",
        "context":"named.resolver_active_queries",
        "units":"queries",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "queries": {
                "name": "queries",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }
    }
    
}
**1:**{
    "net_drops.vpn0": {
        "name":"net_drops.vpn0",
        "context":"net.drops",
        "units":"drops/s",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "inbound": {
                "name": "inbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            },
            "outbound": {
                "name": "outbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }
    },
    "named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default": {
        "name":"named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default",
        "context":"named.resolver_active_queries",
        "units":"queries",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "queries": {
                "name": "queries",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }
    }
    
}
...
```

But I need this kind of result

```
JSON
{
    "net_drops.vpn0": {
        **0:**{"name":"net_drops.vpn0",
        "context":"net.drops",
        "units":"drops/s",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "inbound": {
                "name": "inbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            },
            "outbound": {
                "name": "outbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }},
        **1:**{"name":"net_drops.vpn0",
        "context":"net.drops",
        "units":"drops/s",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "inbound": {
                "name": "inbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            },
            "outbound": {
                "name": "outbound",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }}      
    },
    "named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default": {
        **0:**{"name":"named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default",
        "context":"named.resolver_active_queries",
        "units":"queries",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "queries": {
                "name": "queries",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }},
        **1:**{"name":"named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default",
        "context":"named.resolver_active_queries",
        "units":"queries",
        "last_updated": 1501806176,
        "dimensions": {
            "queries": {
                "name": "queries",
                "value": 0.0000000
            }
        }}      
    }
    ...
}
```

It's possible? If yes how can I do it?

Then I need to slice the objects based on last_update, if the last_update is older than 30 minutes of current time is sliced
Eg: current time 10:00:00, object last_update 09:31:00 is sliced.
It's possible? If yes how can I do it?
Best regards

Comment: What you show here is very different in the link. Can you show us your current approach? Besides, I don't see any array in your code above and in the link.

Comment: Hi,
The correct approach is the json on link, what I showed is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are combining the data with the same key.

To achieve that result, loop through the original JSON data and push it to another array by key. In your case the keys are: 'net_drops.vpn0' and 'named_local.view_resolver_numfetch__default' like: `array.net_drops.vpn0 = json_data`

For the slicing based on the 'last_updated' key, you can try to use `array.filter` function. Check this [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for reference.